# Setting up codemirror.js with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, codemirror

I'm having problems setting up codmirror.js on my site.

I've tried setting up the library the normal way:

```
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

However I get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ()
```

I've included the following configuration for requirejs in my main js file:

```
require([    "/codemirror-4.5/lib/codemirror.js", "/codemirror-4.5/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"
    ], function (CodeMirror) {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
            lineNumbers: true,
            mode: "html"
        });
    });
```

However now I am getting the following errors:

> GET //localhost:54911/codemirror-4.5/mode/css/css 404 (Not Found)
>   require.js:1896 `Uncaught Error: Script error
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:194 GET
>   http://localhost:54911/codemirror-4.5/mode/javascript/javascript 404
>   (Not Found) require.js:1896 Uncaught Error: Script error
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:194 GET
>   http://localhost:54911/codemirror-4.5/mode/xml/xml 404 (Not Found)
>   require.js:1896 Uncaught Error: Script error
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:194
>   generate acc contentCntrl.js:148 GET
>   http://localhost:54911/codemirror-4.5/lib/codemirror 404 (Not Found)
>   require.js:1896 Uncaught Error: Script error
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`

I do not understand why it is trying to load these dependencies locally or even where they are referenced.

Any help in understanding this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It says file not found

Comment: I understand that. However I do not understand where those dependencies are set. If I can change those paths then I can point them to the correct location on my server.

Comment: Show in your question the configuration that you give to RequireJS.

Comment: @Justinvw What you've added in not the *RequireJS* configuration. It looks like the *CodeMirror* configuration.

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't have a requirejs configuration. Only reason I need this to work with requirejs is because I'm using Aloha editor which seems to have caused a lot of libraries to suddenly need to be set up with requirejs. If there is a way I could set up codemirror without requirejs that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies are loaded from other CodeMirror files -- specifically, the htmlmixed mode requires the XML, JavaScript, and CSS modes.

*Don't* go hand-editing those files to change the paths. Instead, keep the CodeMirror directory structure intact, so that the relative paths used to specify dependencies actually work.